# How to use request with SSL website?

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

I configured my sites to run as an HTTPS/SSL site. My server is node.js and the ssl is configured by `nginx` reverse proxy with this configuration:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name example.co.id;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /home/user/www.example.co.id/www_example_co_id.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /home/user/www.example.co.id/www.example.co.id.key;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

}

Now I want to request a data with REST from a node.js app to that server. I use `request` library. I also download `www_example_co_id.crt` and `www.example.co.id.key` directly from the server. Here's my simple code:

```
var path        = require("path");
var fs          = require("fs");
var request     = require('request');
var certFile    = path.resolve(__dirname, 'www_example_co_id.crt')
    , keyFile   = path.resolve(__dirname, 'www.example.co.id.key');

var options = {
    url: 'https://example.co.id/api/movie/show',
    agentOptions: {
        cert: fs.readFileSync(certFile),
        key: fs.readFileSync(keyFile),
        passphrase: 'example',
        securityOptions: 'SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3'
    }
};

request.get(options, function(error){
    console.log(error)
});
```

And here's the result

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1062:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:586:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38) code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
```

I search as many as I can to fix this issue I tried adding `require('ssl-root-cas').inject();` with no working result

Comment: try `require('ssl-root-cas/latest').inject().addFile(certFile);`

Comment: where to put it ? I put that line just before `request.get()` and still get the same error `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`. In the mean time I just create a backdoor link with another domain to make my application work.